# How to restart ssh server / sshd on Linux?

Tags: ssh, sshd, ssh-agent

I am trying to restart the ssh server on my server which is running Fedora Cloud.

I have tried the method here http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-restart-ssh/  (`# service sshd restart`) and get `Failed to restart sshd.service: Access denied`) even when I use `su`.  Any idea how to get around this?

**Edit: When I "disable" Selinux, by setting it to permissive, I get the error:**

```
Failed to restart sshd.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
```

Comment: Is there anything relevant in the logs?

Comment: which log should I check? This is happening while I am `ssh`'d into my server by the way.

Comment: Suggest you run `strace -fo /tmp/foo service sshd restart` and then review the trace output immediately prior to the access denied error.

Comment: you can try to "disable" SELinux temporarily: `setenforce 0`

Comment: `sshd` most probably writes to `/var/log/syslog`, unless it's configured differently on you system.

Comment: You may try this command with sudo or switch as root user and the try restart.

Comment: @steve it appears that `strace` is not installed...

Comment: @Jakuje that did change the error but I still can't force a restart

Comment: I could not find anything in the logs, however, there were many many so I might have missed one.

Comment: So make sure you have policykit/polkit installed and running, as the message advises